# Is it possible to navigate and manipulate video with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, video, raspberry-pi, video-processing

I'm putting together a **Raspberry Pi** project where I capture video for 2 to 3 hours in order to automatically create a montage at the end of the period from an array of timestamps collected during the period.

The plan is to use a button that, when pressed, stores the current times in an array. Assign a listener which, on detection of *record-end*, iterates through the timestamp array, each time capturing the previous 30 secs from the corresponding frame in the video file. Then on iteration completion, save all the captures into a single montage.

Starting/stopping/saving the video and assigning a button to maintain the timestamp array is already working.  What I don't know is what library to use for the video manipulation or even what is possible re what I envision.  I would prefer to use NodeJS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for could be achieved using [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) or [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) (easier api) assuming you have the array of timestamps you could do something like this:

[Cutting a video without re encoding using ffmpeg and nodejs (fluent-ffmpeg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997589/cutting-a-video-without-re-encoding-using-ffmpeg-and-nodejs-fluent-ffmpeg)